# How do I change a PivotCache.SourceData to point to a new Table?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2010, I am copying, via VBA code, worksheets from a Master workbook to a new workbook so that the individual new workbooks can each contain a set of data for different clients.

Some of the worksheets have tables of data pulled from an Access DB, and PivotTables based on that data set. My code copies the worksheet from the master to the new client workbook, updates the data on the worksheet, then updates the `.PivotCache.SourceData` to point to the new workbook.

This code was working just fine to update the `.PivotCache.SourceData`:

```
If XLClinic.PivotCaches.Count <> PivotCacheCount Then
  Formula = NewSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData
  If InStr(1, Formula, "'") > 0 Then
    Bracket = InStr(1, Formula, "]")
    Formula = Replace(Formula, "'", "")
    NewSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData = Right(Formula, _
             Len(Formula) - Bracket + 1)
  End If
End If
```

I then changed my "Master" worksheet layout so that instead of just being some data on the worksheet, I actually defined it as a `table`, and I've manually updated the PivotTable(s) to point to the table name (I changed the table name to something consistent and relevant to the data set, instead of just `TableX`).

This code no longer work to change the `.SourceData` for the pivot table. When I attempt to execute it, I get:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

When the data is simply formatted as a bunch of cells, the `.SourceData` value looks like this:

> '\\server\share\full path[Workbook Name]Worksheet Name'!$A$4:$E$240

When I change the formatting of the data to a table, `.SourceData` now looks like this:

> '\\server\share\full path\Workbook Name`!TableName

With this change in structure in mind, I changed my code to this:

```
If XLClinic.PivotCaches.Count <> PivotCacheCount Then
  Formula = NewSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData
  If InStr(1, Formula, "'") > 0 Then
    Bracket = InStr(1, Formula, "!")
    NewSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData = Right(Formula, Len(Formula) - Bracket)
  End If
End If
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the `Run-time error'1004'`.

I have confirmed that the table in the destination workbook has the same name as the original, it's not getting renamed with a generic name (that's why I'm enforcing a specific name/table on my Master).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally came up with:

```
If XLClinic.PivotCaches.Count <> PivotCacheCount Then
  Formula = NewSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData
  Bracket = InStr(1, Formula, "!")
  Formula = Right(Formula, Len(Formula) - Bracket)
  NewPivotRange = NewSheet.Name & "!" & _
                  NewSheet.ListObjects(Formula).Range.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
  For Each PT In NewSheet.PivotTables
    PT.ChangePivotCache XLClinic.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                                    SourceData:=NewPivotRange)
  Next
End If
```

The drawback to this is that it creates a new PivotCache for *every* single pivot table. When the workbook build is complete, I'll run through some other code I found that will eliminate all the duplicate Pivot Caches to help reduce the size of the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I've found you can also set the pivottable range for the first pivottable, then change the cache of all the other pivottables to the first pivottable's cache.

```
Dim sourceRange As String, sht As Worksheet, pvt As PivotTable, sourcePivot As String
sourceRange = "Sheet1!R1C1:R1000C9"
'OR if in a different workbook: sourceRange = "c:\filepath\[filename.xlsx]Sheet1!R1C1:R1000C9"
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewSheet")
sht.PivotTables(1).SourceData = sourceRange
sourcePivot = sht.Name & "!" & sht.PivotTables(1).Name
For Each pvt In sht.PivotTables
    pvt.ChangePivotCache (sourcePivot)
Next
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
```