# Pivot Table Source will not change Workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Okay, this has been bugging me for a couple of days now.  Hopefully someone can spot a silly mistake somewhere?

### The Premise:

I have a workbook, with data in.  One of the tabs has a list of data in Columns A-D, and a Pivot Table based on that anchored in cell F3.  One of the Macros in the workbook will `Copy` that worksheet (and several others, irrelevant to the question) to a new Workbook with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(aTMP).Copy After:=wkb.Worksheets(wkb.Worksheets.Count)`, where `aTMP` is an Array that contains the Worksheet names.

Unfortunately, this leaves the PivotTable in the new Workbook pointed at the Table in the original Worksheet/Workbook - *not* the new one.  "No problem!", I thought.  "I'll just change the `.PivotCache.SourceData` to point to the correct file - it'll be easy".  Boy was I wrong...

### The Code:

(Including `Debug.Print` statements I added while trying to solve this myself)

```vb
Debug.Print wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData
    'This is "'Z:\FilePath\[WorkbookName]Calculate_PivotTable'!C1:C4"
Debug.Print wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).Columns("A:D").Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    'This is "[Book1]Calculate_PivotTable!C1:C4"
Debug.Print wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceType
    ' This is 1
''''
wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData = _
    wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).Columns("A:D").Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    'This is the line that throws an error
''''
Debug.Print "-----"
    'The following values are after I MANUALLY intervene, as detailed in "The Error"
Debug.Print wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceData
    'This is "Calculate_PivotTable'!C1:C4"
Debug.Print wkb.Worksheets(wsTableAndPivot.Name).PivotTables(1).PivotCache.SourceType
    ' This is 1
```

### The Error:

If I just run the code, I get this rather unhelpful error:

> Error Number -1004
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

**However**, if I put a Break Point on the line that throws the error, *manually* change the Source Data to point to the same Workbook (e.g. Range `A1:D2`), and *then* run the line, it works properly and sets the Source Data to the entire columns.

(N.B.  As I know that Protected Sheets can cause issues with PivotTables I have already checked that there aren't any)

Comment: @FreeMan Creating a new PivotCache seems to have done the trick - I guess there was sort of reference or lock based on the original workbook.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem and posted about it here at SO.

You can see if the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233583/2344413) I came up with will work for you.

Essentially, I created a new Pivot Cache for each Pivot Table from the data on the worksheet. Probably not optimum, but it was the only thing I found that worked.